# Excel: strange #VALUE error behaviour when using UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I know the topic "Excel formulas not updating" has been discussed a lot on many forums but I haven't found a useful solution to my problem.

In a worksheet, I am using built-in Excel formulas as well as own functions written with VBA in the module of the worksheet and I am referencing them within the worksheet.

There is a binary code which gets generated from a hexadecimal code in cell A1. The binary code gets calculated in cell B1.

Let's take following code as an example: 100001101110

Cell C1 contains following:

> =DecodeVal(B1;0;20)

If I now paste a hex code into A1 and the binary code gets created in B1, cell C1 is displaying an `#VALUE!` error.

If I go back to cell A1, click in the textbox and press enter again, the correct value (= 2158) gets displayed.

Why is there a Value error at first, but not if I press enter one more time?

If I paste the binary code directly as text, there is no error at all.

This is the function I'm referring to:

```
Public Function DecodeVal(value, start As Integer, length As Integer) As Long
Dim abschnitt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim valueText As String

    valueText = value.Text
    If (Len(valueText) - start - length + 1 > 0) Then
        abschnitt = Mid(valueText, Len(valueText) - start - length + 1, length)
    Else
        If (Len(valueText) > start) Then
            abschnitt = Left(valueText, Len(valueText) - start)
            length = Len(valueText) - start
        End If
    End If

    Do
        If (Int(Left(abschnitt, 1)) = 1) Then
            DecodeVal = DecodeVal * 2 + 1
        Else
            DecodeVal = DecodeVal * 2
        End If
        abschnitt = Right(abschnitt, length - 1)
        length = length - 1
    Loop While length > 0


End Function
```

Yes, calculation options are set to automatic.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When you paste `100001101110` in the cell, what it display? How the cell is formatted?

Comment: Can you also please share what formula is in cell B1?

Comment: Try please putting a Break point on the line `valueText = value.Text` and see what `value.Text` shows, in both situations. When it works as expected and when not... I suppose that here would be the key of the problem.

Comment: Try changing, `valueText = value.Text` to `valueText = value.Value2` and then test the outcome.

Comment: Side note: If you're passing `value` as a `Range`... then be explicit about that `ByVal value as Range`.

Comment: What should the value of **DecodeVal** be when the `Do` loop is entered ???

Comment: It should be 0. I deleted it for some testing but then forgot to put it back in. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next two things would solve your problem:

1. Change

   `Public Function DecodeVal(value, start As Integer, length As Integer) As Long`

with

```
   Public Function DecodeVal(val As Range, start As Integer, length As Integer) As Long
```

and use `valueText = val.value`

2. Be also sure that B1 is formatted as Text. The best way of formatting would be `TextToColumns`. Manually (from Data Tab) or in code:

   `Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
      Set sh = ActiveSheet
      Set rng = sh.Range("B1:B10")
      rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, fieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)`

   Otherwise, Excel guess can be a scientific format...

Answer (score 2):

Using `Range.Text` is not recommended practice. This will particularly cause errors when the input column has less width than data and cell is displaying `######`. If the formula is calculated then it will return `#VALUE` error. See the snapshot below.

[image]

If you adjust the column width and recalculate it will then show the correct result.

[image]

To get around this, use either `valueText = value.Value2` or `valueText = value.Value` instead of `valueText = value.Text`.

Also, I'd suggest using something like `RngValue` as a declared variable/argument instead of `value` which is a Range property as well (as it may result in conflicts).

Comment: I'm assuming `Range.Text` is indeed the issue... but wondering if OP is using it since the source cell may have number formatting to preserve leading zero(s). In any case there should be a workaround that doesn't use `.Text`.

Comment: you are right, this was the issue. Additionally, I added `CStr`

Comment: @BigBen if you format the cell as number format then the displayed text becomes as I have demonstrated in the first snapshot and the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `Do` loop, you are using `DecodeVal` in calculations, but never assigned it an initial value.

(*there may be other errors*)